# How to create an html Button that start some C# code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

am doing a web app projet on Visual Studio, using the MVC Net core template.
My goal is to Establish tcp request when we clic on a HTML button.
So it fact its simple. When the button is clicked, the model start the part of code that start the tcp request and return the index page as we already are.

**Home Controller**
namespace Flexi_Arm.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
private readonly ILogger _logger;

```
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

public ActionResult HandleButtonOn(string ButtonOn)
    {
    connection:
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1302);
            string messageToSend = "My name is Neo";
            int byteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(messageToSend + 1);
            byte[] sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageToSend);

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("sending data to server...");

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            string response = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(response);

            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("failed to connect...");
            goto connection;
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

**the part of my not working button view** (I tried to use form but I do not think it is the best idea)

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card-body b">

                        @using (Html.BeginForm("HandleButtonOn", "HomeController"))
                        {
                            <button type="submit" name="ButtonOn" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="1">High Power</button>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
```

What should i do, Use Javascript for that? I don't know javascript for now I don't want to learn it if its useless. Im sure its not that hard to do so im wondering.

Comment: Pass a  controller name here Html.BeginForm("HandleButtonOn", "")

Comment: "No web page found at: https://localhost:7246/ButtonOn/HandleButtonOn", 
I have no page, i just want to run the C# code. and return the index view. Do not look to much in my code. I just put it here to show what ive tried.

Comment: @JonasH I know for Http, my app will have to talk with a robot controller that communicate with udp and tcp/ip. thats why I want to communicate via TCP.

Comment: Do you want to get back value back to your index page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BeginForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) would take two parameter [controller action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-html-formextensions-beginform(system-web-mvc-htmlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-object-system-web-mvc-formmethod-system-object)) and [controller name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-html-formextensions-beginform(system-web-mvc-htmlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-object-system-web-mvc-formmethod-system-object)). You are just passing action name, Thus, pass controller name as well.

[image]

Right Approach:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="card-body b">
    
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("HandleButtonOn", "Home"))
                            {
                                <button type="submit" name="ButtonOn" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="1">High Power</button>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Output:

[image]

Redirection After Executing HandleButtonOn:

If you want to redirect back to your Index page after execution within HandleButtonOn action you could write  return `RedirectToAction("IndexView")`  instead return `View("Index")` of to go back to your expected controller action as following:

```
 return RedirectToAction("IndexView");
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought i had to pass HomeController in the controller name where is was just Home Actually

Comment: Glad to assist you on this. No actually Controller name without Controller suffix.